# Can't Debug on Device in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

Several issues when i want to debug ( ARM ) on my WindowsPhone device ...

[Last bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNWS.png)
Can't Debug on Device in Universal Windows App, see:

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
    global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

> error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'if'

Comment: That's not *can't debug*. That's a compiler error, on a line of code for which you've given us no context. Please see [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post to include that [mcve] (code we can copy, paste and compile that will demonstrate the error).

Comment: Hi Ken, I think what I wrote is well defined ... There isn't a compile error, even if I don't put code inside the MainPage.xaml.cs, this error is ON, I can compile it just at Local Machine, on my WindowsPhone I can't do that.

Comment: Of course you think what you wrote is well defined. You know exactly what you're thinking. However, your job is to explain **to us** what that problem is and provide the details that we don't have so that **we** can reproduce it. Again, see [ask] and [mcve]. We can't debug problems with code we can't see.